How to make Vite to generate nested modules?
The parent/lib.ts library will be generated as build/lib.mjs.
Is it possible to make it to respect the nesting and generate it as build/parent/lib.mjs?
It also doesn't use nested names in external option, and includes even if some/lib.ts specified to be external.
Vite respect nesting when used as a config, but not when I use it with this script (I need script because I build many libraries).
import path from 'path'
import { build } from 'vite'

// libs
const libs = ['parent/lib.ts']
libs
  .map(name => [name, path.resolve(__dirname, '..', name)])
  .forEach(async ([name, entry]) => {
    await build({
      configFile: false,
      build: {
        target: "esnext",
        emptyOutDir: false,
        minify: false,
        lib: {
          entry,
          name,
          formats: ['es']
        },
        rollupOptions: {
          external: libs,
          output: {
            // esModule: true,
            // format: 'es',
            entryFileNames: '[name].mjs',
            dir: 'releases/tmp'
          }
        }
      }
    })
  })


https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-entryfilenames - "Forward slashes / can be used to place files in sub-directories."

@J.Titus thanks, but the name already contains forward shash parent/lib.ts. Also, it doesn't respect the external option with nested files.
